# Eliminate label duplicates of spatially close objects

Tags: qgis, labeling, maptiler

I am using a MapTiler vector basemap. It is showing labels for all streets, including highways. These highways often use multiple objects and each object gets their own label. Especially on bigger interchanges, labelling gets a little bit messy:

[image]

In addition, both directions of the highways have their own line, so I often end up with the same label next to each other along the highway, which is unnesessary:

[image]

I've played with the labeling options a bit but I cannot find a way to eliminate these duplicates. Is there even a way to make the GIS know, that there is the same attribute in other objects that are spatially close and make it show only one of them?

I am using QGIS 3.24.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

there is a way how to edit the spacing of labels directly in MapTiler Cloud Advanced editor. I am attaching a picture that documents the effect of adjusted spacing. The default setting is 200, here I put 60, to demonstrate how to multiply the labels "too much".
I guess that you are looking for a value around 400...

You can play with this setting as you like in the MapTiler Cloud Advanced Editor.

Once you are satisfied with the result, you can save the map and connect it to QGIS as WMTS or export the style.json and use it with your local data.

In case you need more info, I am happy to help you.

https://documentation.maptiler.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020949478-Edit-Style-Advanced-customization-of-the-map

[image]